# Converting list with multiple data types(both string and integer) to a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have below list with multiple data types(strings and integers). How do i convert this to a string.

```
sample_list =['a','b',1,'c',2,4,'d']
```

Below statement is not working.

```
' '.join(sample_list)
```

Comment: Because your list include `int` type, You have to covert it to string before `join` to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' '.join(map(str, sample_list))
```

Comment: Why downvote this answer? it's work.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm assuming its because this question is a clear dupe.

Comment: It works. Not sure why a correct answer should be down voted because question is duplicate. It makes sense to down vote a duplicate question.